# only static member be accessed in initializers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I want to try to define below code but when I write it, show me the Error only static member be accessed in initializers, the problem is I can't define it anywhere, the code that I want to define is here, I need to use to calculate discount

`double discount=(prod_old_priceprod_old_price-prod_price)/prod_old_price*100;`

and this my project code:

```
class ProductDetails extends StatefulWidget {
 final prod_fullName;
 final prod_pic;
 final prod_old_price;
 final prod_price;

  ProductDetails({
   this.prod_fullName,
   this.prod_pic,
   this.prod_old_price,
   this.prod_price,
  });
 children: <Widget>[

      Expanded(
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          color: Colors.white,
          textColor: Color(0xff989898),
          elevation: 0.2,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: new Text('Color')),
              Expanded(child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          color: Colors.white,
          textColor: Color(0xff989898),
          elevation: 0.2,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: new Text('Size')),
              Expanded(child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          color: Colors.white,
          textColor: Color(0xff989898),
          elevation: 0.2,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: new Text('Qty')),
              Expanded(child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

    ],
  )
],
```

),
  bottomNavigationBar: Material(
    elevation: 7.0,
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Container(
      height: 60.0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color: Colors.white,

```
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){},
          child: Container(
            height: 40.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 280.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xffff5f60),

              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),

            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'add to cart',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),

            ),

          ),
        ),
      ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xfff40725),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Text("----------------I WANT USE DISCOUNT HERE --------------------------",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            ),

          ),

      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0,left:8.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("\$${widget.prod_old_price}",textAlign: TextAlign.left,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,color: Color(0xff989898),decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),),
              Text("\$${widget.prod_price}",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

      ],
    ),
  ),
),

);
```

Comment: Sorry For UnFormatted Code

Comment: Please either add the whole class or try to show pertinent parts of your code.

Comment: where you want to call this in code : double discount=(prod_old_priceprod_old_price-prod_price)/prod_old_price*100;

Comment: As it is, your code is not understandable. You have mixed several different parts of your class together in a way that anyone trying to copy it and try to understand your issue will have a hard time. Please separate your different relevant snippets.

Comment: @joão-soares I want to use discount in my details page by percent formula , The problem is I don't know how can i use that formula in Text widget, when i try to set it in double variable ,i've got this error in the title , and when i try to set in Text , it doesn't allow me to do that